# Can I use fabric.js to get image data without HTML?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to get the pixel buffer of the canvas.

The size of the canvas is: 64 x 32 pixels with white background.
I add a rectangle object with size, position and color.

Finally when I 'd like to get the 'ImageData.data', I am not getting the correct value.

When trying to use this :

```
let canvasEl = canvas.toCanvasElement();
```

I got an error message that `.toCanvasElement` doesn't exist.

This is the sample code:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

describe('Canvas Manipulation', () => {
    describe('Canvas', () => {
        it('Should create canvas with one rectangle field in black and white', () => {
            let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

            // Size of the canvas (64x32 pixels)
            canvas.width = 64;
            canvas.height = 32;
            canvas.backgroundColor = 'white';

            // Create a rectangle with angle=45
            let rect = new fabric.Rect({
                left: 16,
                top: 8,
                fill: 'black',
                width: 16,
                height: 16,
                angle: 45
            });

            canvas.add(rect);

            // You can use fabricJS to generate a B / W or color image of 32x64 and export it as a canvas element.
            let canvasEl = canvas.toCanvasElement();

            // Once you get the canvas element, you can get the imageData from it.
            var imageData = canvasEl.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height);

            // Then you can loop over the image data and build a 1 bit buffer.
            var data = imageData.data;
            var myBuffer = new Array(data.length / 4);

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
                myBuffer[i / 4] = data[1] > 128 ? 1 : 0;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Best Regards.

Comment: what version of fabric are you on?

Comment: "fabric": "4.1.0"

Comment: First, I am using the fabricjs javascript into a typescript project.

- May be the .d.ts is missing or not up-to-date.

Secondly, I am not using any html page to render the canvas. Just I am creating objects, grouping them, listening event and finally, extract the bitmap array with processing to send to an LCD display.

Best Regards,
Youssef

Comment: But are you running in a browser?

Comment: Dear,

Not at all. I am using just a typescript file for my library.

Best Regards

Comment: toCanvasElement defintely exists, not sure what is happening to you. Are you sure TS definition are not playing a role?

Comment: Dear, Will reinstall the fabricjs module and remove the typescript definition and try.

To be sure, it's clear, would you like to confirm I don't need to use any webbrowser to render the canvas ?

BR

Comment: Create from scratch new typescript project with only fabricjs.
```
    "dependencies": {
        "circular-json": "0.5.9",
        "fabric": "4.2.0",
        "lodash": "4.17.15",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
        "source-map-support": "0.5.16",
        "typedi": "0.8.0"
    },
```
"typescript": "^3.8.3"

Same behavior, toCanvasElement() doesn't exist on type 'canvas'

Error message is :

Property 'toCanvasElement' does not exist on type 'Canvas'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs here](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1) **fabric.js** is (just) a wrapper for HTML canvas elements. In the end the browser does the drawing.

You can't use it without an HTML canvas element that is created by the browser in the DOM.

```
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
```

The value `'c'` has to be the ID of an HTML canvas element that is available in the DOM.

Therefore a test running in **node.js** won't work this way.

Comment: Finally, I got the confirmation of the owner of the fabricjs repository.